# Is a certificate of experience valid after the organization has closed down?

Tags: software-industry, work-experience, india

I am from India and I got an offer from a software company here. The human resource team of that company asking me to submit evidence of 36 months of valid experience when joining. I have that, but 9 of those months were with a company that has closed down more than 2 years ago. The company is not currently active.

Given this, will the experience certificate from the closed down organiation be  valid? Can I produce that to the HR team? Will it pass the background check which will be conducted by them?

Comment: It seems to me if you have proof you worked for a company that existed at one point, the fact they no longer exist, isn't in your ability to control.  Why don't you ask the HR team if it will be accepted they in end make that choice.

Answer (score 3):

I have answered on a similar situation [here (my co-worker died)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/interviewers-doubt-my-freelance-work-due-to-no-proof-as-my-friend-coworker-pas/10621#10621). Since you worked there, then you should add it on the list of the places you've worked on. I cannot see any other feasible alternative like introduce a gap while you were employed.

You should describe that the company is not trading explaining that you can supply proof that you were there such as payslips, bank account extracts for payments, co-worker contacts etc.

This has happened to me: I was able to locate my ex-CEO from linked-in. He has signed a letter describing my time there and his contact details. I attach it in job applications.

Since there is a lot of mobility in the software industry, I would advise (for the future) to get into the habit of collecting related material as soon as you go. After that you could have it in your own domain/github/dropbox for people in the future. For example after giving your notice to that company, you could have requested a letter about your time there, tasks and employment or a reference letter from a manager. Then you could have it ready for situations like this. Unfortunately software developers unlike say graphic designers cannot have a portfolio to "carry" with them between jobs/clients. Another idea would be to get screenshots of emails for being congratulated, finishing projects etc. Prevention VS cure.

Answer (score -1):

1. At one point in time, I worked for four successive employers in New York City's highly volatile Silicon Alley, all of whom went out of business. Emphatically, the fact that they went out of business does not detract in any way from the fact that I acquired the work experience and skills set.
2. I was able to use, when needed, my former bosses and senior colleagues as references. And their willingness to back me up was the proof that prospective employers needed to verify my story. If they want more from you, they'll ask. You may have additional evidence in the form of correspondence or business cards that your former employer gave you.